# Can I use autolink on kramdown with GitHub Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

GitHub Pages will support kramdown only after May 1 [1].
I want to use autolink.
Is there any solution w/o upload generated html files?

[1] https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0

Comment: gh pages already supports kramdown : "Starting May 1st, 2016, GitHub Pages will only support kramdown...". So, the answer is yes.

Comment: Kramdown doesn't support bare URL auto-links, only minimal Markdown links with angle braces surrounding them, so the answer to whether you can use autolink with Kramdown on GitHub Pages doesn't appear to be "yes"